# Cron running only the latest entry made into crontab

Tags: php, cron, curl

I'm recording entries into crontab using PHP (`www-data` user). The first entry is a scheduler that runs every minute. If the scheduler finds a specific criteria it adds new entry to crontab. After I add an entry, the scheduler (that should run every minute) stops working. The cron jobs aren't running in parallel. It is like the `www-data` user could only execute a single cron job.

My scheduler, which works when it's the only thing in the crontab:

```
* * * * * curl --silent http://myapi_url/scheduler >/dev/null 2>&1
```

When the scheduler runs, it adds a new entry:

```
18-59/2 * * * * curl --silent http://myapi_url/user/10 >/dev/null2>&1`
```

So the new entry works, but the scheduler stops working. If I add yet another new entry, the two previously added stop working but not the new one. Why?

EDIT:

The crontab looks like this:

```
* * * * * curl --silent http://myapi_url/scheduler >/dev/null 2>&1 
18-59/2 * * * * curl --silent http://myapi_url/user/10 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

each new entry comes below.

Comment: Because you are doing it wrong  .. what are the content of your crontab after adding the second entry ?  What command are you using to add the second and following entry to crontab ?

Comment: @SorenA I edited my answer.

Comment: Please use either four spaces at the beginning of a line or the `{}` button in the editor to format blocks of fixed-width text.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. When writing to Crontab I was using the line break incorrectly and due to this at the end of the entry a ^M was recorded.